# Is there a C++ API for a dynamic reconfigure client?

Tags: c++, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a C++ API that I can use from within a C++ node that will create a dynamic reconfigure client? I would like my node to be able to modify some of the [base_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner#Parameters) parameters, such as the min/max velocities, during run time.

I have looked at the [dynamic_reconfigure wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) and the [client API](http://ros.org/doc/electric/api/dynamic_reconfigure/html/dynamic_reconfigure.client.Client-class.html) pages and I only see a way to use a Python client node to update variables on a dynamic reconfigure server.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12276/is-there-a-c++-api-for-a-dynamic-reconfigure-client?/) by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4347 on 2011-12-08

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Achim](https://answers.ros.org/users/1188/achim/) on 2012-01-05**:
I'm looking for this, too and till today did not find anything. :(

**Comment by [Kai Bublitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1332/kai-bublitz/) on 2012-03-08**:
Just came across the same problem. The use a dynamic_reconfigure server in TrajectoryPlannerROS, but according to the wiki there still is no C++ api. Or has anyone found out if there is a (hidden) C++ api that can make a client?

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-09-02**:
fivef's answer is great! Just as a follow up, someone was inspired by fivef's answer and posted a more detailed example [here](http://ros-robotics.blogspot.com/2016/03/controling-dynamic-reconfiguration-from.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like someone added a C++ API in June 2016. I'm not sure how to use it or how it compares in performance to the python Client, but you can see the commit details here https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/pull/63.

---

Originally posted by [gillamkid](https://answers.ros.org/users/41437/gillamkid/) with karma: 36 on 2019-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-05-25**:
I made this as the selected answer as this refers to the official api for Kinetic onward.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had quite a hard time implementing this.
So here my example:

`/joint_commander` is the node the dynamic_reconfigure server runs in.

Includes:

```
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/DoubleParameter.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Reconfigure.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/Config.h>
```

In your function:

```
dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureRequest srv_req;
dynamic_reconfigure::ReconfigureResponse srv_resp;
dynamic_reconfigure::DoubleParameter double_param;
dynamic_reconfigure::Config conf;

double_param.name = "kurtana_pitch_joint";
double_param.value = pitch;
conf.doubles.push_back(double_param);

double_param.name = "kurtana_roll_joint";
double_param.value = yaw;
conf.doubles.push_back(double_param);

srv_req.config = conf;

ros::service::call("/joint_commander/set_parameters", srv_req, srv_resp);
```

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-05-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 34

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) on 2013-09-19**:
This worked flawlessly, thanks so much!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-08**:
I tried to implement this in the same node that was providing the dynamic reconfigure service, and it blocks forever in the default setup which only has one thread- the solution is to use an AsyncSpinner with at least two threads, and wrap critical stuff in mutex locks.

**Comment by [postal](https://answers.ros.org/users/25034/postal/) on 2016-03-15**:
Do you have some examples of that?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-15**:
No public examples, but I implemented a server along the lines of http://wiki.ros.org/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/SettingUpDynamicReconfigureForANode(cpp) and then adapted the above code, and then instead of ros::spin() I did `ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1); spinner.start();`

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-03-15**:
Though I'm not sure why I didn't do spinner(2) for two threads, and why there wasn't a waitForShutdown() as in http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning - I'm looking at code that is ifdeffed out, unfortunately.

**Comment by [Sam lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/32897/sam-lee/) on 2017-12-06**:
In my case, when I adjust that code, my dynamic reconfigure was died....
everyone is working well?

**Comment by [achmad_fathoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/32710/achmad_fathoni/) on 2018-09-22**:
So it can't be called from callback?

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-03-09**:
This worked for me on JADE with 14.04 LTS to configure RASPICAM node. Used from within a private class function (called from with a callback)

If fivef is still around, Thank you!

**Comment by [So Young](https://answers.ros.org/users/67634/so-young/) on 2021-01-18**:
This still works really well, I tried it with DWA local planner in Navigation stack. thanks!!